# How to exclude non-working days and holidays in between two dates?

Tags: sql, date, datetime, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT date1, To_Char(date1,'DY'), date2, To_Char(date2,'DY'), Trunc(date2-date1) Days
FROM Table_Name WHERE Trunc(date2-date1) > 0
```

This gives me the records which have the day-difference of more than 1 days. Now, I have to find out if a holiday or a saturday falls between the two dates. And if it does, then I have to exclude it from the 'day-difference' and show the results.

```
DATE 1      DAY1    DATE2    DAY2    DAY DIFFERENCE

19-MAY-12   SAT   21-MAY-12   MON            2
18-MAY-12   FRI   21-MAY-12   MON            3
18-MAY-12   FRI   21-MAY-12   MON            3
18-MAY-12   FRI   22-MAY-12   TUE            3
18-MAY-12   FRI   22-MAY-12   TUE            3
18-MAY-12   FRI   22-MAY-12   TUE            3 
05-JUN-12   TUE   07-JUN-12   THU            2
05-JUN-12   TUE   07-JUN-12   THU            2
```

I tried this but there are a few hitches. I'm working on them.

```
SELECT transaction_date, TO_CHAR(transaction_date,'DY'), deposit_date, TO_CHAR(deposit_date,'DY'), trunc(deposit_date - transaction_date + 1) Total_Days,
trunc(deposit_date - transaction_date) -
(CASE 
    WHEN TO_CHAR(date1, 'DY') IN ('SAT') 
         OR date1 IN ('25-JAN-13', '27-MAR-13', '29-MAR-13', '01-APR-13', '24-APR-13', '09-AUG-13', '15-AUG-13', '30-SEP-13', '02-OCT-13'
         , '13-OCT-13', '16-OCT-13', '03-NOV-13', '14-NOV-13', '17-NOV-13', '25-DEC-13') 
    THEN 1 

    WHEN TO_CHAR(date1, 'DY') NOT IN ('SAT') 
    THEN 0
END
+
CASE
    WHEN TO_CHAR(date2, 'DY') IN ('SUN', 'SAT')
    OR deposit_date IN ('25-JAN-13', '27-MAR-13', '29-MAR-13', '01-APR-13', '24-APR-13', '09-AUG-13', '15-AUG-13', '30-SEP-13', '02-OCT-13'
    , '13-OCT-13', '16-OCT-13', '03-NOV-13', '14-NOV-13', '17-NOV-13', '25-DEC-13') THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
END 

) BUSINESSDAYS 

FROM Table_Name

  DATE 1   DAY1   DATE2   DAY2   WORKING DAYS

19-MAY-12   SAT 21-MAY-12   MON     1
18-MAY-12   FRI 21-MAY-12   MON     3
18-MAY-12   FRI 21-MAY-12   MON     3
18-MAY-12   FRI 22-MAY-12   TUE     3
18-MAY-12   FRI 22-MAY-12   TUE     3
18-MAY-12   FRI 22-MAY-12   TUE     3
18-MAY-12   FRI 19-MAY-12   SAT     1
```

Comment: The best long term solution is to use a [calendar table](http://www.perpendulum.com/2012/06/calendar-table-script-for-oracle/), this can store working days, weekends, bank holidays etc, and will make many date related queries much easier in the long run.

Comment: Can you post a concrete solution specific to this problem here as an answer to this problem?